# How to share internet Hotspot/Wifi that require Login To Own Wifi Without PC?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, repeater

In my rented room, there is a paid internet which seems to use mikrotik hotspot. Which must login to access the internet. Unfortunately, the username only allowed for a single login.

**I did not ask about the brand**, but is there any tool/Hardware on the market that can share the internet connection from one username to a lot of device by creating **new own  Wifi?** for now I can do it through software such as virtual router. But for me this is inconvenient. 
It Wifi repeater can do this?

Thanks

Comment: if it's lan, you can share it to wifi with an ad-hoc network and that should work (although you are rather cryptic with your information on how logins work)

Comment: No, its not lan. it used Wifi Hotspot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a router or router-wifi modem.

The wifi modem simply connects into a wifi scheme for things that don't have wifi.  The router bit sets up a network on the other side, but you can let guest machines on as well (eg visiting relatives).

So your router is logged in to the mikrotik wifi system.  You actually log into your own router, and you can set your own passwords etc.  You can have a different router password.

So you have:  internet connection = mikrotik connection and password.  You are a client to this, it's not your area of management.

router:  You have a password to log into something like 10.0.150.1, or whatever free range is to hand.  The router id and password is simply to manage the router.  You set a different SSID and Password for the user-machines, eg (myrouter)

user machine:  You find your SSID as the hotspot to use, and then enter the SSID password to access the router and internet.  This is how people with a single internet connection and 38 machines do it.

So you are actually running your own Wifi, and this is completely portable, and the only thing that changes is your internet provider id/password.

You can get some really tiny devices here.  They make them for extending a telephone internet connection into a local hot-spot for travellers.

Comment: it's potentially possible to do this without a router if your computer has 2 wifi cards or uses an internal and usb wifi

Comment: The whole point of having a router is so you don't have to have a computer on all the time.  I imagine what Arief has in mind is to have the laptop on the table (on or off), and snuggle up to bed with his phone.  On top of this, the G/F can come around and use her tablet.  And that's it.

Comment: Problem Solved, What i need is router that have WISP mode (Wireless Internet Service Provider). I was bought only $13. And Works! Thanks ! 

Info:
AP Client Router Mode(for WISP user Internet sharing)
With AP client router mode, it can connect to a wireless network and share the connection to its clients. The wireless is its WAN side. It can also support Dynamic IP/Static IP/PPPoE/L2TP/PPTP.
When the wireless station limits the number of clients or asks username/password to connect, AP Client Router Mode is what you need.